# Are there any method to copy primitive arrays on collections and vice versa and wrapping/unwrapping them automatically?

Tags: java, arrays

For example: this code is correct because I'm using Integer objects

```
Integer[] numbers = {32, 3, 5, 57, 1};
List <Integer> list = new ArrayList <> (Arrays.asList(numbers));
```

How I can to copy an array of primitive int like this?:

```
int[] numbers = {32, 3, 5, 57, 1};
```

I know that I can use a for-each with the array, wrap each int data and then use add() but I want to know if there are any method to make this directly.

Comment: you can only use `system` 's array copy function for same primitive type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's the way using `Apache commons`

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils;

List<Integer> longs = Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(new int[] {1,2,3,4}));
```

or using

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4};
int<Long> list = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: If I use apache commons or guava can I to have compatibility problems when a user tries to run the progran in a PC without commons/guava?

Comment: just add required `Apache` jar into the class path and you have your problem solved or add jar in your eclipse build path

Comment: "Vote up requires 15 reputation" I'm sorry! XD

Comment: @VicenteParra mark it as accepted answer using mark symbol with green color, if it helped you my friend :)

Comment: Ahhh ok, ok, I'm new in this and I'm some comfused.

Answer (score 6):

In Java 8 you can use streams for slightly more succinct code:

```
int[] primitives = {32, 3, 5, 57, 1};
List<Integer> objects = IntStream.of(primitives)
                                 .boxed()
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The other way around is something like this:

```
int[] primitivesAgain = objects.stream()
                               .mapToInt(n -> n)
                               .toArray();
```